# Getting error response while Attempt to hit a API

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to post device token and device details to a web service using almofire. But I am getting response like the following

UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fba3a590e50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://----/register, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://---/register, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.

In Objective c, I tried to set all the values as httpHeader, In swift i used the following code..

```
let params = ["notification_token":deviceToken,"device_identifier":deviceIdentifier,"advertising_identifier":"","model":deviceModel,"os":deviceOS,"os_version":deviceOSVersion,"app_version":deviceAppVersion]

let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])

request(.POST, urlString, parameters: params,encoding:.JSON).responseJSON
                {
                    response in

                    if let JSON = response.result.value
                    {
                        // print("A JSON Result :\(JSON)")
                        delegate.API_CALLBACK_RegisterApp!(JSON as! NSDictionary)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        delegate.API_CALLBACK_Error(0,errorMessage: response.result.error!.description)
                    }
            }
```

Please assist me..

Comment: disable app transport security in your app, or whitelist a specific url

Comment: Thanks Bro, Working fine :)

Comment: Now it works fine and insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable the App Transport Security.

**You have to set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your .plist file. Hope this helps!**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Add This key to your info.plist
[image]